# Is there a fix for the endless "Scanning for Steam games updates."?

Tags: steam

On trying to fire up any game in Steam, or Activate a Product on Steam, a popup will display stating "Scanning for Steam games updates.", and just sit there. It never does anything, and only offers a Cancel button (which sometimes is even disabled), which doesn't allow me to start the game from Steam.

I assume it's never going to stop, it's been going for minutes, so, is there a way around this, a way to fix this, or a way to disable this scan?

[image]

Comment: I think this question goes too far from the main topic of this website. You really should write to Steam's support if you encounter a bug with Steam.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Steam is most decidedly on-topic for Arqade.  It's a program that most gamers use, and I think we're pretty good experts on solving various issues that crop up.

Comment: Any chance you can restart Steam?  I've had similar issues, and that usually resolved them.

Comment: @fbueckert Restart of Steam didn't work, but a reboot cleared it up. Thanks. /me hangs head in shame when I don't do the obvious.

Comment: Okay, now I was sitting here 2 minutes waiting for Steam to start because I just launched it, but it was already open in the background...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few things you can try:

- Restart Steam.
- Reboot your Computer
- Wait until its done.
- Rename the file `ClientRegistry.blob` to `ClientRegistry.bak`. By default you should find this file under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`. This will force steam to generate a new .blob file and might fix your problem.
- Disable and exit steam-limiter if you have it

Answer (score 4):

I've found that logging out (via change user) and logging in again fixed it for me

Answer (score 3):

A solution that I have found is to go to steam>settings>account then click the "change" button next to beta participation and choose to participate. This works because the latest beta update fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes sufficient to kill Steam.exe from the Task Manager, then launching it again.

Answer (score -3):

Just click on the steam button on the top left corner and go online